# Is there any difference between class and staticClass in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is there any difference between `class` and `staticClass` in Vue.js render functions? Using [Template Compilation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Template-Compilation), I can see that it outputs different results depending on what is passed to HTML `class` attribute.

For example, when I pass a single string (for example `'foo'`) it outputs `staticClass` in [data](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#The-Data-Object-In-Depth) object:

```html
<div class="foo"></div>
```

compiles to:

```js
function anonymous() {
  with(this){return _c('div',{staticClass:"foo"})}
}
```

but when I add a colon `:` (shortcut for `v-bind`) in front of `class` attribute it outputs `class`:

```html
<div :class="'foo'"></div>
```

compiles to:

```js
function anonymous() {
  with(this){return _c('div',{class:'foo'})}
}
```

**I am curious about the difference between `class` and `staticClass`, and which one should i use when writing own render functions.**

I have googled a little, but have not found any clue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have a conditional CSS to apply for the element, use `:class`, whereas when to represent the element you can use `staticClass`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key difference is that `staticClass` can only be a string. `class` supports all the other formats, such as arrays and objects.

The `class` attribute is special in many ways. For most attributes you can't specify both a bound and non-bound version on the same element. It also needs to be merged differently when combining the attributes from nested components. All of this merging happens here:

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/531371b818b0e31a989a06df43789728f23dc4e8/src/platforms/web/util/class.js

When templates are compiled down to `render` functions they employ a number of undocumented features to take advantage of extra knowledge that comes from the template. This would be one such example, where it knows that an unbound `class` can only be a string so it tries to retain that knowledge by storing it separately as `staticClass`.

In theory there are a couple of advantages to that:

1. Manipulating the value doesn't need to worry about the array and object forms of `class`.
2. The `staticClass` can never change, so there's no need to check it when updating the DOM.

However, in practice that second optimisation isn't implemented (there's something that looks similar in the template compiler but it's not quite the same thing). Further, it's not entirely clear from looking at the code that there's much gained from a manipulation standpoint either. If anything it looks like it just makes things more complicated trying to maintain the two separate concepts right until the last possible moment. Perhaps the benchmarks suggest otherwise...

As for which one you should be using in your `render` functions, only `class` is documented so I'd stick with that:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#The-Data-Object-In-Depth

Comment: Thank you a lot. You are the best of the best!